# Ionic Build Failed with "Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'"

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to build Ionic app with:

```
$ ionic cordova build android
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.964 secs
Error: /Users/Nasser/IonicProjects/baitkum-full/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
/Users/Nasser/IonicProjects/baitkum-full/platforms/android/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:71:28-52: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@string/accountkit_token').

/Users/Nasser/IonicProjects/baitkum-full/platforms/android/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:69: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@string/accountkit_token').



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

    cordova build android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Can you please help me find the issue?
Thank You

Comment: Still having the issue! Anybody please?

Comment: Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.3.1
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 6.3.0
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.1, (and 15 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v10.13.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : macOS Sierra
   Xcode  : Xcode 8.2 Build version 8C38